# サイトを別ドメインの下層ページに移転する際のhtaccessの設定について

Tags: apache, .htaccess

お世話になります。

サイト移転を行う予定なのですが、少し特殊でして、

現在のサイトを他ドメインの下層ページに移動するという
形を考えております。

現在のトップページ
https://old.example.jp/

引っ越し後のトップページのURL
https://new.example.jp/abc

なお転送するのはトップページへのアクセスだけでなく、下位ページに対しても必要になります。

この場合のhtaccessの記載方法、進め方がわからず
もしわかりましたらご教授をお願いできますと幸いです。

知識がなく大変恐れ入ります、、、

お手数をお掛け致しますが、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この書き方だと下層ページに対してでなければ(新ドメイントップに対してであれば)理解しているのかな？という印象ですが、如何ですか？ / 転送するのがトップページへのアクセスだけでいいのか、下位ページに対しても必要なのか、辺りも書いておくと詳しい回答が付きやすいのかなと思いました。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: 転送するのはトップページへのアクセスだけでなく、下位ページに対しても必要になります。説明が不足しており申し訳ございません。

Comment: 追記でApacheのバージョン情報も記載いただけますか？htaccessの記述方式はバージョンによって変わることもありますので。